# Python Loop function to extract first column name only when conditions are met in row in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have dataframe with large number of row and column. I am trying to write a loop which will check all row for particular condition which when true only return me only 1st column name. I need to store the column name and value in new Dataframe.

dataframe will be something like this:

```
         col1  col2  col3  col6  col7  col8  col9
Name                                             
John        0    23     0     1     4     1    23
victor      1     4     5     2     1     4    15
Alida       1     1     2     6     0     2     2
Natalie     0     1     1     4     2     3     4
Morman      3     3     1     0     5     2     1
```

I am trying to get the first column name for each  value which is greater than or equal to 4 and result will be stored in Dataframe df2 which will something like

```
Name       Greater Than 4
John       col2
victor     col2
Alida      col6
Natalie    col6
Morman     col7
```

I am new to python. I am trying something like following Code:

```
df2["Name"]=df1["Name"]
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if df.iloc[:,[index]] >=4:
        df2["Greater Than 4"]=df.iloc[:,[index]]
```

Comment: You can use `df.idxmax` here...`df.ge(4).idxmax(1)`

Answer (score 2):

If there as at least one value greater or equal by `4` use [`DataFrame.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ge.html) with [`DataFrame.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html):

```
s = df.ge(4).idxmax(axis=1)
print (s)
John       col2
victor     col2
Alida      col6
Natalie    col6
Morman     col7
dtype: object
```

If not sure, so possible incorrect output add [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) with test by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
print (df)
         col1  col2  col3  col6  col7  col8  col9
John        0     0     0     1     1     1     2
victor      1     4     5     2     1     4    15
Alida       1     1     2     6     0     2     2
Natalie     0     1     1     4     2     3     4
Morman      3     3     1     0     5     2     1


print (df.ge(4).idxmax(axis=1))
John       col1 <- incorrect value, because no match
victor     col2
Alida      col6
Natalie    col6
Morman     col7
dtype: object

mask = df.ge(4)
s = mask.idxmax(axis=1).where(mask.any(axis=1), 'no match')
print (s)
John       no match
victor         col2
Alida          col6
Natalie        col6
Morman         col7
dtype: object
```

Last for DataFrame use:

```
df2 = s.reset_index(name='Greater Than 4')
```

For maximal value and maximal column name is possible use:

```
df2 = df.where(df.ge(4)).agg(['max','idxmax'], axis=1)
print (df2)
        max idxmax
John     23   col2
victor   15   col9
Alida     6   col6
Natalie   4   col6
Morman    5   col7
```

Comment: Thank you for reply . I have 2 follow up issue . 1st: it looks dataframe.ge is trying compare 1st column which is string which fails. 2nd: Is there anyway to retrieve compared data along with column name

Comment: @EdNS - So  use before my solution `df = df.set_index('Name')`

Comment: Thanks that fixed ! Is there anyway to retrieve value as well ? @jezrael

Comment: @EdNS - Then use `s2 = df.where(df.ge(4)).max(axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

data.csv:

```
Name col1 col2 col3 col6 col7 col8 col9
John 0 23 0 1 4 1 23
victor 1 4 5 2 1 4 15
Alida 1 1 2 6 0 2 2
Natalie 0 1 1 4 2 3 4
Morman 3 3 1 0 5 2 1
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter=' ')
df = df.set_index('Name')
print(df, '\n')

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(index, row[row >= 4].index[0])
```

Output:

```
         col1  col2  col3  col6  col7  col8  col9
Name
John        0    23     0     1     4     1    23
victor      1     4     5     2     1     4    15
Alida       1     1     2     6     0     2     2
Natalie     0     1     1     4     2     3     4
Morman      3     3     1     0     5     2     1

John col2
victor col2
Alida col6
Natalie col6
Morman col7
```